# circuitikz: labels, component size, and documentation

Tags: circuitikz

I'm trying to pick up `circuitikz` tonight to draw a few circuits. I ran into a few problems.

**Problem 1: Positioning Labels**

Here's my problem. When I use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw[scale=0.8, transform shape] 
                (5,0) -- 
                (5,-2) to[battery, l=$1.5\ V$, i=$\SI{3}{A}$] 
                (0,-2) -- 
                (0,0) to[resistor,  l= $R_2$ ] (5,0);
        \draw[scale=0.8, transform shape] 
            (3.5,1.5) to[resistor, l=$R_3$] 
            (1.5,1.5)-- 
            (1.5,-1.1) to[resistor, l= $R_1$ ] 
            (3.5,-1.1) -- (3.5,1.5);
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image: circuit]

I can't figure out how to get the R_3 label above the resistor.

**Problem 2: Scaling components**

I've been using the `scale` and `transform shape` options, but is there a better way to change the size of each component and label?

Related, is there a way to get thicker lines?

**Problem 3: Documentation**

I've only been able to find [this document](http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf) for documentation, and I don't think it's very comprehensive. Is there a better resource?

If not, can you please explain a better way of drawing my circuit than the way I've done it. Mine feels really amateurish...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Problem 1: Positioning Labels**

This can be solved quite easily since [`circuitikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) defines also `l^` and `l_` to locate the labels. In this case `l_` is the option needed.

**Problem 2: Scaling components**

The options `scale` and `transform shape` are always a way since [`circuitikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) exploits TikZ, but there are also specific keys to change size of the components; you find some examples in the documentation 6.2 Components size.

To get thicker lines, one can always use the standard TikZ keys `thick`, `very thick` and so on or `line width`.

Here is an example which more or less answers to all the request (just illustrative: the combination of `thick` with that bipoles' length is awful):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.8, transform shape,thick] 
    \ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.85cm}
        \draw   (5,0) -- 
                (5,-2) to[battery, l=$1.5\ V$, i=$\SI{3}{A}$] 
                (0,-2) -- 
                (0,0) to[resistor,  l= $R_2$ ] (5,0);
        \draw
            (3.5,1.5) to[resistor, l_=$R_3$] 
            (1.5,1.5)-- 
            (1.5,-1.1) to[resistor, l= $R_1$ ] 
            (3.5,-1.1) -- (3.5,1.5);
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

For problem 3, unfortunately I can not point a better resource.

Comment: Just in time. This was a perfect answer. Thank you!

Comment: @algebralives: you're welcome `:)`